# Django media image not displaying

Tags: django, media

I am developing a django app were i am uploading images through the admin panel 
i have implemented this in my other apps but i can seem to get what is wrong with my configurations as follows

settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'ntakibariapp.Member'
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = 'ntakimbari:_login'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'media')
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
```

)

urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('ntakibariapp.urls')),
    path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls'))
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, ducument_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

models.py

```
class Community_work(models.Model):
    where = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    time = models.TimeField(blank=False)
    date =  models.DateField(blank=False)
    image_of_area = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos',blank=True)
    post_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.where
```

template/communtity_work.html

```
{% extends 'temp/base.html' %}
{% block title %}community works{% endblock %}
{% block body %}

<div class="container">
  {% for work in works %}
   <p>Picture of the area <img src="{{work.image_of_area.url}}"></p>
   <p>Where: {{work.where}}</p>
   <p>Time: {{work.time}}</p>
   <p>Date: {{work.date}}</p>
  {% endfor %}
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Can you get the image by directly visiting the image url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in urls.py you have a misspell try use 
`document_root`
instead of `ducument_root`

Comment: using a good IDE with autocompletion avoid this kind of errors.

Answer (score 0):

Also shouldn't the tag be `<img src="{{community_work.image_of_area.url}}">`?